# Does it make sense to copy your own content and post it to another site without any canonical links?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, rel-canonical

I have a website that is copying the same exact content to another server that is more web 2.0.  This is happening without a canonical link. Does it make any sense to do that? Won't it end up with duplicate content issues?

Comment: The title and the question in body is totally different for me.

Comment: @Goyllo The original post matched the title a bit more.   Some of the edits (while needed for grammar) wandered a bit from the original.   I've edited in a way that is more consistent with the title and (I think) a bit more in line with the original.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in that this is against Google's best practices. One of them will be flagged as a duplicate and will not show up in searches alongside the other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Google will consider that contents are duplicate and links from duplicate/think content is consider as zero or spam value in any of link metrics(Pagerank, Page Expert score, trust score etc).

It's not about weather Google index it or not and consider duplicate or not, but such a links is never good for any website, specially when your site is quite new and have not earned natural backlinks.

But If you're not doing that for SEO then use noindex tag on your blogspot article so Google don't index it and  use nofollow link to your main article.